# convert data in js structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting data from php like :

```
[{'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, {'lat': 32.2334, 'lng': -86.2085}, {'lat': 32.2334, 'lng': -86.2085}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396`enter code here`}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396}, {'lat': 38.6207, 'lng': -83.8067}, {'lat': 42.3644, 'lng': -71.0633}, {'lat': 40.0625, 'lng': -79.8953}, {'lat': 34.4197, 'lng': -119.7078}, {'lat': 42.8142, 'lng': -73.9396}, {'lat': 42.0702, 'lng': -72.6227}]
```

but in js i want to convert this like :

```
const locations = [
  { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
  { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
  { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
  { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
  { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
  { lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657 },
  { lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905 },

];
```

can anyone please suggest me how can i convert this in this way. i want to remove the single quotes and want new array of result like this

Comment: Is this an ajax response, or something being embedded in JavaScript code by PHP, or...?

Comment: no its not the ajax response getting from the controller like var values = "{{myValue}}" in this way i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no its not the ajax response getting from the controller like var values = "{{myValue}}" in this way i am getting

In that case, it's fine as-is if you remove the wrapper quotes — JavaScript is fine with single-quoted property names in object literals:

```
var values = {{myValue}};
```

What the JavaScript engine will see is:

```
var values = [{'lat': 31.5755, 'lng': -85.279}, /*...*/];
```

which is fine.

---

If it were an ajax response, your best bet would be to fix the PHP so it provides valid JSON (double quotes rather than single quotes). Then you could just parse the result with `JSON.parse`.

As a second-best solution, if you can't do that, since the only single quotes in the data are the ones around the property names, you could replace them with double quotes and then parse the result:

```
const locations = JSON.parse(theDataString.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

**But**, that only works because there aren't any other single quotes. It's not a good approach; fix the PHP side instead.